# Toggle row using html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

In app.js in a `react.js` `node.js` `express` application,

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
...
```

I create rows dynamically. I can see the rows fine in the browser. I wrote code that toggles hiding/display a `tr`

```
...
toggleRow : function(id) {
      var row = document.getElementById(id);
      if (row.style.display == '') {
        row.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
         row.style.display = '';
      }
    },
...
```

In Firefox "Inspect Element" I see the row with the right Id (outer html).

```
<tr id="optionA" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0"><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.0"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.1"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.2"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.3"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.4"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.5"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.6"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.7"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.8"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.9"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.a">.PGC150</td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.b">34.60</td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.c"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.d">5</td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.e">5</td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.f"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.g"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.h"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.i"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.j"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.k"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.l"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.m"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.n"></td><td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$=1PGC150.0.o"></td></tr>
```

However, the code that toggles the row doesn't have any effect on the table on the web page.

```
toggleRow("optionA");
```

**Is it correct to use html style code `document.getElementById(id)` in a node.js/react/express application? If not, what is the correct replacement code that toggles a row by ID?**

Comment: Yes, `document.getElementById` in a React application is totally fine. Node and express don't have a document object though so you won't have much use for that API when creating for example an express server.

Comment: I am confused slightly by your response. It seems like you are saying it is totally fine, but then say there is no document object? The code above doesn't work, so I am not sure how to think about your answer.

Comment: If your code is running in a web browser and there exists in the DOM an element with the ID of  of what the variable `id` contains, the code should work fine. Express however isn't intended to run in a context that has a document object. It's a server. It serves files that browsers will ultimately render within their document objects, but `document._____` within an express application is going to get you a reference error.

Comment: It doesn't work. Sigh :-(

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: I got it to work. I need to say: this.toggleRow(id); not just toggleRow(id). It correctly toggles hide/display.

Comment: One strange thing now is that some rows lose their style, meaning that there are no cells "boxes" around some of the rows but there are on others. Interestingly, it is only the rows beneath the row that I am hiding that has this problem. Well at least I got something to work.

Comment: I refreshed the browser and now that behavior went away and I can't reproduce it. Oy vey, this is voodoo programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is OK to use `getElementById()` in React programs, but I personally only use when I need to use non-React libraries (such as D3).

In you case, a more React-y way to achieve it would be to:

- store the visibility state of each row in your React element (props or state)
- toggle this boolean within your `toggleRow` function
- use this boolean to render or not each row

Quick sample with a `ul` list (not tested):

```
const handleToggleElement = (e, that) => () => {
    // copy the element and finds its index in the list
    const newE = Object.assign({}, e)
    const i = that.state.list.indexOf(e)
    // copies the list and modifies the element
    const newList = [...that.state.list]
    newE.shouldDisplay = e.shouldDisplay ? false : true
    newList[i] = newE

    that.setState({ list: newList })
}


const myList = React.createClass({
    render: function(props) {
      return
          <ul>
          {
            this.state.list.filter(e => e.shouldDisplay)
              .map(e =>
                <li>
                    e.content 
                    (<a onClick={handleToggleElement(e, this)}>(hide)</a>)
                </li>)
            }
            </ul>
    }
})
```